# Configuring g++ from Code::Blocks doesn't take affect on command line

Tags: c++, windows, gcc, command-line, g++

I'm trying to change the settings of g++ from the Code::Blocks IDE. I went to the `Settings` tab, clicked `Compiler...` and checked various options for the compiler to use, like

- Enable all warnings (`-Wall`)
- Have g++ follow the C++11 ISO C++ language standard (`-std=c++11`)
- **......**

These are just two of many others; when I compile on the command line, here is what comes up:

> ```
> g++ -o example example.cpp
> # warning: initializer lists only available with -std=c++11 ...
> ```

Notice how there's no warning either - I have an unused variable in my program. It only works if I give the options manually:

> ```
> g++ -Wall -std=c++11 -o example example.cpp
> ```

Do you think I might have done something wrong when setting up the compiler? Why aren't the options taking affect?

Comment: *When I configure the fonts in Word, and I then I open Chrome, the changes are not picked up in the browser*

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas But Code::Blocks uses the g++ compiler and when I compile on that IDE it works just fine with those options selected...

Comment: @templateboy, Yes, and both Word and Chrome use the fonts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Invoking the compiler from the ide is completely independent from doing it in a command line shell. There's no reason for the setting and usage of one to have any effect on the other.

Comment: So how do I get it to work so I don't have to specify options manually?

Comment: You could build your project from codeblocks? Or you could wrap the `g++.exe` or `gcc.exe` in a batch script or similar that automatically includes your desired options.

Comment: @templateboy: Simple answer, use a makefile or any other build tool. Set the options in the build system. Hardcore crazy rant: recompile the compiler with your desired flags set by default

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Reply to hardcore rant: How do I do that??

Comment: @greatwolf Okay, forget I said that!! `:)`